# Babylon.js sandbox scene stucks at loading

Tags: javascript, 3d, blender, babylonjs

I've made everything as instruction said... exported `blender` scene to `.babylon` format with their exporter. It made 27MB `.babylon` file.

But when I try to load it in [sandbox](http://www.babylonjs.com/sandbox/), `Loading` image appears, and nothing happens, except one error in console:

```
GET http://www.babylonjs.com/sandbox/null 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Have you opened your files like this?

1. Hit the button on the right (open files).
2. Choose `.babylon` file and textures associated with it (hit CTRL and choose the files).

I forgot the textures so it fixed my problem. In case it is not your problem, can you link the files?

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic error, but make sure to try that:
OPen the Sandbox with IE 11 or CHrome.Drag & drop will not work with Edge.
Always drag and drop the babylon file and the related textures.